# Dependency conflict but they both want same package version

Tags: python, pip, kats

I am trying to install kats using `pip intall kats`, however I get the following error:

```
ERROR: Cannot install kats==0.1.0 and kats==0.2.0 because these package versions have conflicting dependencies.

The conflict is caused by:
    kats 0.2.0 depends on pystan==2.19.1.1
    kats 0.1.0 depends on pystan==2.19.1.1
```

I am confused about the error as it seems they both depend on the same version of pystan, so they shouldn't be a conflict? How can I get around this error?

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

Create a `conda` environment in a particular directory

```
conda create --prefix ./env python=3.7
```

Install `fbprophet`

```
conda install -c conda-forge fbprophet
```

Install `kats`

```
pip install kats
```

Downgrade packaging to 21.3. Change line 178 in the `site-packages\holidays\registry.py` file in the `conda` environment
from `super().init(*args, **kwargs)` to `super().init()`.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me like the error message is misleading in its phrasing, the real issue seems to be that it is impossible to have both `kats==0.1.0` and `kats==0.2.0` installed at the same time in the same environment. I do not know how *pip* came to the conclusion that it needed to install both.